# How to read csv file and display specific column on php?

Tags: php

I have an csv file with rows and columns and I want to display column C and E. My result is always coming with everything like that: `aaabbbcccddee`. Any idea how to do it separate like `aaa bbb ccc dd ee` and showing only C column and E column?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without your code..

Comment: Errrr... `$var1 . " " . $var2`?! `foreach($var as $x){ echo $x . " "; }`? Pure guesswork of course, just like your code.

Comment: hope now its better i added the code

Comment: Please add an extract of the file as well. From your comments below, I suspect your file is not a comma delimited file.

Answer (score 1):

Only print the columns you want

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
        echo 'Data is ' . $data[2] . ' ' . $data[4]
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The fgetcsv() function allows you to specify a delimiter, which in the above example is a comma (","). You can specify other delimiters, for example tabs ("\t").

Inside the while loop, the fgetcsv() command will return an array of values read from your line.

Therefore if your line is

```
111,aaa,bbb,ccc
```

Then $data will be

```
Array (
   [0] => 111,
   [1] => aaa,
   [2] => bbb,
   [3] => ccc,
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but is not showing my data on the file :/

Comment: replace the echo with "print_r($data);" What does it show?

Comment: It showing like this Array ( [0] => onetwothreefourfive ) Array ( [0] => 12345 ) Array ( [0] => aaabbbcccddee ) but the space between them are still missing.

Comment: It looks like your file is not a comma-delimited file. Please paste the first 5/6 lines of you file in the original question above.

Comment: Aww thank you. Yeah the file was not a comma delimited file. Now its working. Thanks a lot

Comment: But what are the code to show only one column? such as I want to see only ccc and ee.